# How to attach policy to a role while creating an AWS lambda function in nodejs in AWS CLI? Facing error while attaching role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-lambda

I am creating a nodejs application and deploying it as a lambda function on AWS. I am following the link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-create-iam-role.html

I am now stuck at step 2.2-2.3. Step 2.2 has the json with the policy that needs to be attached to the role. When I use the below command (step 2.3) to create the lambda function:

```
ws lambda create-function --region us-east-1 --function-name LambdaFunctionOverHttps --zip-file fileb://LambdaFunctionOverHttps.zip --role execution-role-arn --handler LambdaFunctionOverHttps.handler --runtime nodejs4.3
```

Then I get the below error:-

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
>   CreateFunction operation: 1 validation error detected: Value
>   'execution-role-arn' at 'role' failed to satisfy constraint: Member
>   must satisfy regular expression pattern:
>   arn:aws:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@-_/]+

I even created the file "execution-role-arn" which had the json from Step 2.2. How can I resolve this error and create the lambda function?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error, turns out you have to specify the Role ARN, not the Role name. So instead of `--role roleName` , put `--role arn:aws:iam::1234567891:role/service-role/roleName` . You can find you role ARN by clicking on the role name in **Roles** tab, and then at the top you'll find the role ARN.

AWS really needs to fix their documentation for almost all of their services.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The role needs to be replaced with the actual arn role name for the lambda function instead of a separate file. This can be found on the role you just created in step 2.2. So, the proper way to do this is as follows:

> aws lambda create-function 
>   --region us-east-1 
>   --function-name LambdaFunctionOverHttps
>   --zip-file fileb://LambdaFunctionOverHttps.zip 
>   --role arn:aws:iam::9999999999999:role/lambda-gateway-execution-role 
>   --handler LambdaFunctionOverHttps.handler 
>   --runtime nodejs4.3

This worked out fine and the lambda function got created. Note that I had pointed the default profile to admin with the aws config command.